# Symfony getUser and save to form

Tags: plugins, symfony1, sfguard

I have a symfony form with a few hidden fields that the user can't edit but are set automatically when they submit the form.   The one field I can't seem to set is the userID.   The form is secured so it requires authentication in order to display (sfDoctrineGuardPlugin).

What I'm looking for is for the form to set the "user_id" field to the currently logged in username.  I have tried this in the class file.

```
    if ($this->isNew() && ! $this->getSeller_Id())
    {
        $this->setSeller_Id($this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getUsername());

    }
```

But it always returns an error stating that there is no User field in the current table.  I hope I explained that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set user_id in hidden field. Someone could change it via firebug. I preffer to use this code inside proccessForm()

try this (edited):

```
    $form = new YourForm();
    $this->user = $this->getUser()->getObject();

    $form->getObject()->setSellerId($this->user->getId());

    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()));
```

Comment: I've read about the firebug and I really don't want this to be a field they can change.   I tried your fode in the processForm() function in the actions.class.php file of my module and it threw a flag so I changed it to '$user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();' and '$this->setDefault('seller_id', $user->getUsername());' but now it errors out saying that "Call to undefined method carActions::setDefault."  I even tried changing it to SetParameters and it bombed out too.   Let me know what to do to make it work.   Thanks!

Comment: Without the first and last lines, it worked.   lol.   Thanks a million guys.

Comment: I still found the solution from @olivierw better than this one. What if you want to use your form in an other action? You will have to copy the code from Piotr and paste it in the new action (which introduce duplicated code). Instead of that, the code from olivierw will be in the form class, so you won't have to copy/paste code into the new action. Just call the form and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the username as an option to the form. In your controller:

```
 $myform = new myObjectForm(NULL, array('username' => $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getUsername());
```

Then in the `doSave` function of your form:

```
 public function doSave($con = null)
 {
    if ($this->getObject()->isNew() && !$this->getObject()->getSeller_Id())
    {
        $this->getObject()->setSeller_Id($this->options['username']);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is not working for me.   It keeps saying that the Car table (which is the name of my table) doesn't have a field called "Object".  I found an article online with this code 

$userid = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getUsername();
   and then    $this->setseller_id($userid);

But I read somewhere that you should stay away from using "Instance"

Comment: this code (doSave) must be in the form class, not in the object class!

Comment: Pardon my ignorance.   I am new to symfony and the terminology is a little confusing at times.   What files do I put them in?  When you say form class, is that the CarForm.class.php file?  Also which file is the controller?  The frontend_dev.php file?

Comment: No problem! Controllers are in `app/frontend/modules/[moduleName]/actions/actions.class.php` and yes, form class is the `CarForm.class.php`. Note that the `doSave` function is available only if your form extend `BaseFormDoctrine`. Have a look to http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_sub_generating_model_forms